# What is meant by “redundant, but not duplicative” in the Steelman language requirements?

Tags: programming-languages, code-quality, language-design, specifications

The [Steelman language requirements](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Steelman_language_requirements) have this:

> The language shall require some redundant, but not duplicative, specifications in programs.

I think I can see the underlying idea (that re-stating things may lead to fewer errors given the limitations of human cognition), but I would like a more detailed explanation.

What do they mean by “redundant” and by “duplicative”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean that you shall be required to write things that could reasonably be inferred from other things in the code.  But you will not be implementing the same thing twice.

An example of what they mean is type systems.  You might be able to infer the existence and types of variables from their usage, but the redundancy of explicit declaration can catch errors.

If in doubt think about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29 because it is what came out of this effort.

Answer (score 3):

In this context "redundant" means that program's behavior is described multiple times. But "not duplicative" means that each of the of the specific types behaviors is different.

For example, automated testing. The code is "redundant", because the behavior is described twice : once in code and once in form of automated test. But it is not duplicative, because both cases use completely different way to express what they do.

At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: This is more or less what I imagined, too. I will wait before accepting in case others wish to chime in.